# Creating a requestCounter service in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

I'm trying to make it so that I can just add "requestCounter" to any controller and get a value that is constantly updated with the number of requests. The interceptor code is working, however the value provided by injecting requestCounter is always `{count: 0}`. What am I not understanding!

```
angular.module('theApp')
  .provider('requestCounter', function ($httpProvider) {
    this.$get = function () {
      var activeRequests = 0;
      var obj = {count: activeRequests};
      $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.push(function(data) {
        activeRequests++;
        return data;
      });

      $httpProvider.defaults.transformResponse.push(function(data) {
        activeRequests--;
        return data;
      });

      return obj;
    };
  });
```

the controller

```
angular.module('theApp')
  .controller('PurchaseCtrl', function ($scope, requestCounter) {
    $scope.requests = requestCounter;

  });
```

the markup

```
<h1>There are {{requests.count}} requests loading</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning you are assigning a primitive value of activeRequests = 0 to your obj, so they are not linked to each other. You can try with:

```
var activeRequests = {number: 0};
var obj = {count: activeRequests};
```

Then you can have your counted number in obj.count.number

Comment: Ahh, I see what i did wrong.  I just need to get rid of `activeRequests` because primitives are copied by value. `var obj = {count:0};` and then in the interceptors do `obj.count++` and `obj.count--`. Thx!